# Floating point arithmetic and comparing of floating point values

Tags: java

For these lines of code, I get back 0 as an output that is they are all equal to each other. Now if I understand correctly, a b and c may store slightly different versions of the true value .3 hence when do a Float.compare(...) against these values, I expect to get back as an output a value other than 0. Why do I get them as 0?

```
float a = 0.15f + 0.15f;
float b = 0.1f + 0.2f;
float c = 0.3f;
System.out.println(Float.compare(a,  b));  //<--- outputs 0
System.out.println(Float.compare(a,  c));  //<--- outputs 0
System.out.println(Float.compare(b,  c));  //<--- outputs 0
```

Comment: Just because floating point isn't accurate enough in general doesn't mean it isn't accurate enough in a specific case.

Comment: You can add to your question that for `double` values it doesn't work this way (you get `-1`, `0`, `1` because result of `0.1d + 0.2d` is `0.30000000000000004` where other numbers are `0.3`).

Comment: @Pshemo: `0.1d` is as inaccurate as `0.1f`, just with more decimal places. No floating-point precision is capable of representing 0.1, it is a repeating series in base-2.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, I know. I just suggested to put this info in question so OP could better express what results ware expected.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman you're right, and so is Pshemo. It's just that with the 64-bit precision of a double, the inaccurate representation of 0.1 added to the inaccurate representation of 0.2 is different than the inaccurate representation of 0.3. With 32-bit precision floats this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as you say, they *may* store slightly different versions. But with these simple expressions, there is no loss of precision, so a, b and c all contain exactly the same version of `.3f`.

For fun, try this. Here you will lose precision, and the result of the comparison will not be `0`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float a = .3f;
    float b = .3f;
    a = (float) Math.cos(a);
    a = (float) Math.acos(a);
    System.out.println(Float.compare(a, b));
}
```